# Storing songs on MySQL Database (BLOb support)

Tags: java, mysql, database, blob

I am trying to store songs and lyrics on MySQl db. I googled for examples how to do this,but no help.However,i am able to store images:

```
  con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "");
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO image VALUES(?,?)");
 File file = new File("E://guitar.gif");
FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(file);
ps.setInt(1,id);
ps.setBinaryStream(2,fs,fs.available());
int i = ps.executeUpdate();
ps.close();
con.close();
//rest code
```

Can anyone help me how to store songs?with example?and how to retrieve it back?

Comment: I think MySQL was designed to store photos and recipes in the first place, but not songs. Just kidding. Are you getting an exception?

Comment: @mbelow with above code?nope!

Comment: What is the state after executing the query? Is a new record created at all? Is the blob field empty? Please provide more information.

Comment: @mbelow after executing the query,the BLOb field contains the binary data something like this 000011010000000.... (suppose to be)
It does creat a new record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing different in storing a song than storing an image. You could add another column for the file name's, and the you can do something similar to store the files:

```
//..
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO data_table VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
//...
ps.setInt(1,id);
ps.setString(2, file.getName());
ps.setBinaryStream(3, fs,fs.available());
int i = ps.executeUpdate();
//...
```

An then to retrieve it:

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT file_name, content from data_table where *some condition*");
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
while(rs.hasNext) {
    rs.next();
    String fileName = rs.getString("file_name");
    Blob blob = rs.getBlob("content");
    byte[] content = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());
    //now content contains the data, you ca store it in a file if you need
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("d:/test/" + fileName));
    os.write(content);
    os.close();
}
```

Don't forget exception handling!

EDIT: Another version with byte arrays:
Write:

```
//..
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO data_table VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
//...
byte[] content = new byte[fs.available()];
ps.setInt(1,id);
ps.setString(2, file.getName());
ps.setBytes(3, content);
int i = ps.executeUpdate();
//...
```

Read:

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT file_name, content from data_table where *some condition*");
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
while(rs.hasNext) {
    rs.next();
    String fileName = rs.getString("file_name");
    byte[] content = rs.getBytes("content");
    //now content contains the data, you ca store it in a file if you need
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("d:/test/" + fileName));
    os.write(content);
    os.close();
}
```

Comment: +1 for answer.can you please explain:

 ps.setString(2, file.getName());
ps.setBinaryStream(3, fs,fs.available());

Comment: `setString` is for setting file's name (optional, I think it would be useful when retrieving the file back) and `setBinaryStream` for setting the file's content.

Comment: one more thing.does that code saves file in d drive? if yes,i can't find it :(

Comment: it is not inserting the sound file.:(

Comment: It was not inserting sound file.Then i changed fs.available(); to fs.read(),it worked:),but still,having problem with reading

Comment: It shouldn't work with fs.read(), that returns the first byte in the file, not the file's length.

Comment: otherwise it is not inserting

Comment: Packet for query is too large (24951347 > 1048576). You can change this value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet' variable.
this was the error