# How to retrieve an audio file stored from MySQL database and play back in java?

Tags: java, mysql

I successfully stored all my 'wav' audio files in MySQL database.But i am not able to retrieve it back.Please help me to retrieve it back in database itself.

I connected  MySQL database to java.I want to retrieve the audio from mySQL database and playback in java.

I need a code for my above problem.Please help me to retrieve the audio and playback  in both MySQL and java.

Please suggest me a solution..

Comment: Are you sure that you stored *the files* in the MySQL database or did you store just *a reference* to those files (a URI or whatever?). In addition, please provide what you have already tried (e.g. a code sample you came up with that fails)...

Comment: you might have stored the reference links for those audio files.

Comment: Check Out [**This Link**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13608866/storing-songs-on-mysql-database-blob-support)

It was done with mysql databse and java

Answer (score 0):

in your Database try to store only the name of your file.waw and then save it in a local folder of project. Execute a "SELECT ..." statement for retrieve it (name.extension) and then load your audio's file...

Try Java Sound API for playback.

Comment: If you store the file in the local project folder, why would you need a database? I don't even get the scope of the question: Are we talking about a (web) applet, an android app or just a (local) program?